# Webcam and microphone support by Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I've tried to find a way how I could enable webcam and microphone in the Tor Browser, but didn't succeed. All testing websites that I've tried (https://www.onlinemictest.com/, https://webcamtests.com/, etc) don't detect the webcam and the microphone. Tried the Tor Browser on Windows and on Linux - result is the same.

Is it possible to use webcam and microphone in the Tor Browser in general? (It is clear that there are security/privacy considerations when using webcam/mic in the Tor Browser, but still).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many security risks to using your camera with the Tor browser on websites. I'm pretty sure your location would be leaked in most cases. That said, let's move on.

---

With normal browsers (e.g. Google Chrome, Safari, Microsoft Edge, etc.), websites would use your camera and microphone through an API known as WebRTC. But, the Tor browser disables as it can leak your IP address and location.

> We also disable the WebRTC API as mentioned previously, since even if it were usable over Tor, it still currently provides the local IP address and associated network information to websites.

> To prevent proxy bypass by WebRTC calls, we disable WebRTC at compile time with the --disable-webrtc configure switch, as well as set the pref media.peerconnection.enabled to false.

Source: https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design

So if you set `media.peerconnection.enabled` to true and disabled the `--disable-webrtc` flag, you could enable webRTC. You would also have to make sure you aren't automatically blocking websites from asking permission (Go to `about:preferences#privacy` and click on camera and microphone settings to see if you are automatically blocking) and that you have JavaScript enabled.

---

There is another way, but it's no safer:

You can install the Brave Browser which has a Private Window with Tor. Brave doesn't disable WebRTC unless you modify your settings. This Private Window with Tor let's you use the Tor network right in the Brave Browser. This let's you visit websites with the Tor network and use your camera/microphone.

---

But why do you want to use your camera and microphone in the Tor browser anyway? It would deanonymize you and could potentially endanger you.

Comment: Thank you. --disable-webrtc flag is exactly what I was missing. This flag is set at compile time. So if I understand it correctly, the only way to get webrtc working in the Tor browser is by re-compiling it on my own, right? I am aware of all security issues with webrtc, I am only interested in a theoretical possibility of using webcam/microphone in the Tor browser.

Comment: @mskov yes, webRTC will only work in the Tor browser if you remove the --disable-webrtc flag and also set media.peerconnection.enabled to true.